# Cannot call method '_set_active' of undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have just updated ajaxcontroltool kit(7.1213)  in nuget c# vs2012. it keep on prompt me this message when i want to change tab active page.

Cannot call method '_set_active' of undefined

does any one facing the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

sorry , i just found out a solution.

I have changed from

```
 TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex = 2;
```

to

```
TabContainer1.ActiveTab = tab2;
```

tab2 is the tab panel

Comment: instead I used TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex = 0; fixed my issue!